# How do I decide which runner to use for Apache Beam?

Tags: python, apache-beam

I'm using Apache Beam 2.40.0 in python.

It has [10 different runners](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/) for jobs.

How do you choose which one to use?  The [DirectRunner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/) seems like the easiest one to set up, but the docs claim it does not focus on efficient execution.

Answer (score 1):

DirectRunner runs the pipeline on a single machine. It's hardly used in production. There is also an [InteractiveRunner](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/interactive) wrapper for Python SDK that mostly uses DirectRunner in an IPython/Notebook environment to execute small pipelines interactively for learning and prototyping.

To process large amount of data in a distributed manner, the runners with the best support (document/support-wise) and most popularity currently are:

- DataflowRunner: if you want to use Google Cloud services and want a more serverless experience without worrying about setting up your clusters.
- FlinkRunner/SparkRunner: if you prefer setting up your own EMR solutions or using existing services that allows you to provision clusters with optional components (there are also serverless options for these runners out there).

As for other runners, you may refer to the runners section of the [roadmap](https://beam.apache.org/roadmap/) for the newest update.